# Upload image to s3 via Pre-Signed url not working (Typescript)

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-s3

In my situation, I know my `fileuploadurl` is working perfectly. When I try on postman, I can upload the file and I get everything I want. But I don't know why this not working on my project on angular.

I use the same access, but at the end of the upload the response is : 400 (Bad Request).

```
uploadfileAWSS3(fileuploadurl: string, file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': file.type });
  const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', fileuploadurl, file, { headers: headers, reportProgress: true })
  return this.http.request(req)
}
```

The documentation to know more : https://medium.com/@aakashbanerjee/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-the-browser-using-pre-signed-urls-4602a9a90eb5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, be careful if you have the same situation. Even if you have a correct header, make sure you don't have an injector.

The problem is amazon s3 won't tell you sometimes, so try it on Postman and compare the header to be sure.

Un easy way to reset the header :

Your import :

```
import { HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http' // to add
```

Your constructor :

```
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private handler: HttpBackend // add this one 
  ) { }
```

And finally your method :

```
  uploadfileAWSS3(fileuploadurl: string, file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {  
    this.http = new HttpClient(this.handler); // to reset the header
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': file.type });
    const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', fileuploadurl, file, { headers: headers, reportProgress: true })
    return this.http.request(req)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this answer! After almost a day of investigation, I found your code sample, did paste it without changes and it's working.  Not sure that HttpBackend usage is a key, but it's working on angular 9!